# Вывод противоположного значения из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список, множества

Есть список с двумя элементами (их всегда два):

```
any_list = [5, 7]
```

И значение:

```
item = 5
```

Как мне красиво/правильно получить противоположное значение из списка?

В данный момент на ум приходит только функция-хелпер

```
def get_another_item(any_list, item):
    for i in any_list:
        if item != i:
            return i
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно использовать результат логического выражения (`0`/`1`) в качестве индекса.

***Пример:***

```py
any_list = [5, 7]
item = 5

r = any_list[any_list[0] == item]  # 7
```

Comment: Спасибо, это явно лучше моего решения!

Answer (score 5):

Вот вам еще пример, для разнообразия:

```
any_list = [5, 7]
item = 5

res =(set(any_list) - set([item])).pop() # 7
```

Answer (score 4):

```
any_list = [5, 7]
item = 7

r = any_list[~any_list.index(item)]
```

либо так использую `xor`

```
r = item ^ any_list[0] ^ any_list[1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Решение с использованием словаря

```
>>> dict((any_list, any_list[::-1]))[5]
7
>>> dict((any_list, any_list[::-1]))[7]
5
```